# Font problem with Gsmartcontrol

Tags: fonts, 18.04

When I use Gsmartcontrol with Ubuntu 18.04, I have a tiny font problem:

[image: Gsmartcontrol font problem]

Does someone have an idea about how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution :

> sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C

or by editing /etc/default/locale

> sudoedit /etc/default/locale

the line LC_NUMERIC=C must be added.

The problem comes from the fact that LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 with Ubuntu 18.04 and that numbers are badly represented by some applications.